# jQuery append div to parent sibling or children?

Tags: jquery, parent, each, siblings

I have the following HTML

```
<li class="post" style="width: 621px;">
    <div class="mediaholder">
        <div class="mediaholder_innerwrap overlay cap-icon enlarge">
        <a href="#" class="view" data-rel="lightbox" rel="lightbox">
            <img width="440" height="330" src="#" class="attachment-portfolio-index wp-post-image">
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="detailholder">
        <h4 class="post-title"><a href="#">Example Title One</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="post" style="width: 621px;">
    <div class="mediaholder">
        <div class="mediaholder_innerwrap overlay cap-icon enlarge">
        <a href="#" class="view" data-rel="lightbox" rel="lightbox">
            <img width="440" height="330" src="#" class="attachment-portfolio-index wp-post-image">
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="detailholder">
        <h4 class="post-title"><a href="#">Example Title Two</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I'm trying to move the `.post-title` class inside the `a.view` class within each `li` using this jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.post-title').each(function () {
        $(this).parents('li').next('a.vew').append(this);
    });
});
```

For each `post-title` I take it and append it to the parent li a.view but it's not working.

I tried the below which appends the `post-title` inside the `mediaholder`, i'm having trouble getting this class into the `a.view` class. This is what i've got working http://jsfiddle.net/Zn6Eq/1/ if you can fork / update i'd really appreciate it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.post-title').each(function () {
        $(this).parents('li').children('.mediaholde').append(this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have few problems like a typo in class name `vew` also it is a descendant of `li` so need to use `find()` not `next()`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.post-title').each(function () {
        $(this).closest('li').find('a.view').append(this);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yBEYF/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('h4.post-title').each(function () {
        $(this).parents('li').find('a.view').append(this);
    });
});
```

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TLC9r/3/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example of your fiddle:

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zn6Eq/8/)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.post-title').each(function () {
   var obj = $(this).parents('li').find('a.view');
        $(obj).append(this);
        alert($(obj).html());
    });
});
```